# How do I fix this fatal error in OpenCart?

Tags: php, opencart

I am using CSV Import Pro to import products into my store using OpenCart.

The other day I was importing products which was going fine. Then after an import the extension keeps giving me this fatal error.

I've tried contacting support for damn near 5 days and I haven't gotten much from them. I really need to get this fixed.

**Fatal error:** Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /home/content/71/11151671/html/admin/view/template/tool/csv_import.tpl on line 234

Usually there are tabs at the top that let me navigate to the other pieces of the module.

It would not let me post images

Comment: Would you like to show a few lines around line 234 in that code please. But basically the code must be doing exactly what the error says, you are treating an object as if it were an array and it does notlike it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the CSV Import Pro you want to go to the admin/controller/tool/csv_import.php

Search for this line of code:

```
$this->data[$key] = json_decode($this->data[$key];
```

and replace it with:

```
$this->data[$key] = json_decode($this->data[$key], true);
```

By adding the true at the end, you are basically telling the script you want your data to be in an array format, rather than an object.

Hope this helps ;)

Peter

Comment: Sweet!

This problem haunted me for days.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Glad you got it :P :)

Answer (score 1):

Without code sample it's really just guessing, but my first impression is that you're trying to access some members of an object that was processed with `json_decode`. This will, by default, turn arrays into objects, to be more exact instances of PHP's `StdClass`. Either try accessing the members using object notation ($obj->member) or use the 2nd optional parameter to `json_decode` in which case the returned will be an associative array instead of an object.

[See PHP doc for json_decode](https://www.php.net/json_decode).

Answer (score 1):

If you split a JSON-object, try to add a second parameter to the function `json_decode`:

```
$json = json_decode($string, true);
```